# Playing audio on iPad

Tags: ipad, html, audio

I'm working on a website that has a chat for a client, however, we're experiencing problems with audio in iPad (iOS 5).

The target is in fact the iPad with support for IE7 is preferred.

I've tried these approaches:

**HTML5**

```
<audio id="notification" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/notification.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="audio/notification.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

With some javascript

```
var el = document.getElementById('notification');
el.play();
```

---

**Some javascript function** I stole somewhere which in fact are two different methods in one function. Please note the script is in a subdir, so the path is correct.

```
function notify() {
    var url = '../audio/notification.mp3';
    var a = document.createElement('audio');

    if(!!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType('audio/mpeg').replace(/no/, ''))) {
        var sound = new Audio(url);
        sound.load();
        sound.play();
    } else {
        $('#notification').remove();
        var sound = $('<embed id="notification" type="audio/mpeg" src="'+url+'" loop="false" hidden="true" autostart="true" />');
        $(body).append(sound);
    }
}
```

Both methods doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, the answer was somewhat obvious.

After a lot of time spending doing research etc, I've found [an article](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html) in the official documentation of Safari saying:

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play button works, but an onLoad="play()" event does not.

So, basically, you can't launch a sound without the user triggering it at first. As solution I created a mute button that is off on default, so you have to click it which plays the notification sound. Afterwards I can use Javascript to play the sound without user interaction.

Thank you Safari for this great future. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Gah, come on Apple, the user action is loading the web page, so *two* user actions are required (loading a page, then doing something else). Same problem with trying to trigger the native keyboard.

Comment: @Tim S:  Are you saying that, for a given web page: once the user loads the page then clicks the play button that you could then play audio whenever you like on that page? say, in response to a mouseover event?

Comment: A sound won't play or pre-cache if it's *not* triggered by an user event. So I guess you can use an hover event to play or load a sound, yes. Please don't forget that you can't hover on touch-screens.

Comment: I have understood this thing, but with my code the repetition of the sounds does not work.
I opened a question here if you can help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73716844/audio-on-ios-does-not-work-properly-it-only-works-the-first-time

Answer (score 6):

With the release of iOS 6 for iPad audio playing during an onLoad is still not supported for iPad.

For iPhones with iOS 6 audio will only play during an html site's onLoad if there are headphones plugged into the audio jack on the iPhone.

Answer (score 5):

The Apple iPad does not allow playing sounds without a user click previously initiating it.

Solution: Add a play/pause button.

```
App.toggle_audio = function(elem) {
  var icon = elem.find("i");
  var playing = _.include(icon.attr('class').split(" "), "icon-pause")
  if (playing) {
    elem.html("<i class='icon-play'></i> " + App.translate_play_audio);
    App.play_audio_toggle = false;
  } else {
    App.audio_file.load();
    elem.html("<i class='icon-pause'></i> " + App.translate_pause_audio);
    App.play_audio_toggle = true;
  }
}
```

Once the user clicked the button once the Audio is loaded. You can then play it via Javascript.

```
  if (App.play_audio_toggle) {
    App.audio_file.play();
  }
```

Comment: I stumbled across this problem and found a way to solve it. Then decided to post the code I use to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Source code(version simple)

### HTML

```
 <div id="enableSound"> Enable Sound</div>
```

### JS

```
var sound = new Audio("/Assets/audio/yourAudio.mp3");;
 $("#enableSound").click(function() {
     sound.play();
  });
```

User has to click on div "#enableSound", from that moment on whenever you want to play above sound, just call

```
sound.play()
```

http://jsbin.com/virixukavo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the MP3 as the first source rather than the second one. The iPad used to have an issue where it always played the first source no matter what (it might have been fixed by now though - but it's worth a try).

Also try changing the `type` to `audio/mp3`.

Comment: Unfortunately, both didn't work. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Odd. Have you verified that it works on a desktop browser? So you can ensure the paths to the audio files are correct?

Comment: I can certainly confirm it did work on Desktop. Also, the sound if the iPad is in fact on, haha!

Comment: So that was the issue? :-) Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: I didn't sort anything! It still doesn't work unfortunately... I'm just saying that it works on desktop and not on iPad.

Comment: Ah ok, I had misunderstood what you wrote, apologies. Difficult to help further I'm afraid, as I don't have an iPad myself. Is QuickTime installed on the iPad? (I assume so but it's worth checking)

Comment: I found the answer and I have posted it. Thanks a lot for your help anyway!