# audio is not auto played in i-pad

Tags: html, ipad, safari

```
<audio id="resource_audio" controls preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="cat.mp3"></source>
    <source src="cat.ogg"></source>
</audio>
```

This above code works fine in desktop browsers but when i run this on i-pad audio is not autoplayed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179585/playing-audio-on-ipad

Comment: @Yashhy -thanks for giving reference link