# Can't play HTML audio element via JavaScript on iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The below code is a snippet of an audio player component I built. It works perfectly in all desktop browsers (including the latest Safari), but fails on iOS 8 and 9. I checked the Safari debugging console (linked to iOS Simulator) and there are no errors or warnings. `audio.play()` just doesn't seem to do anything. I've Googled around quite a bit and have had no luck.

If I make `<audio>` visible by adding the `controls` property, I can hit play on my audio component and then play on the `<audio>` element controls, and it works. After that point, my audio components' controls (play, stop, pause, seek) all work perfectly. There's something about it being told to play by JavaScript that's failing.

Also, the `canplaythrough` audio event never fires off. This is usually triggered after setting `audio.src` to a valid audio file, and it has a chance to buffer.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  const audio = this.refs.audio;
  const {command, url, seekTo} = newProps.audioPlayerData;

  switch (command) {
    case 'play':
      if (audio.src !== url) {
        // Doesn't match the URL we're currently streaming
        audio.pause();
        audio.src = url;
        audio.play();
      } else {
        // This track is being played after having been paused
        audio.play();
      }

      break;

    case 'pause':
      audio.pause();
      break;

    case 'stop':
      audio.pause();
      audio.src = '';
      break;

    case 'seek':
      audio.currentTime = seekTo;
      break;
  }
},

render() {
  return <div>
    <audio ref="audio" src="" />
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember having the same issue a few years back and also remember that this is not a bug but something that the iOS browser has specified on purpose. It is not possible to have something autoplay in Safari browsers as per their specification. You can only offer a play button, so that the user can choose to play it.

This is because they might be on a data plan and get charged for the download of the music. I found this in this [source](http://feedback.dominknow.com/knowledgebase/articles/30293-why-won-t-my-mobile-device-audio-or-video-play-aut).

In your case, using Flux to trigger the JS function play() causes iOS to think that this is not a user triggered action but something coming programmatically (which is not allowed as per their own specification). Taking out the Flux logic and triggering play with a user gesture, will fix this problem. I guess, iOS is not ready for React's way of thinking just yet :)

Comment: I'm not auto-playing though. I'm triggering a play via JavaScript. And oddly enough, it works perfectly if I start a fresh React project from scratch but use my `AudioPlayer` component. Weird. It must be an issue elsewhere...

Comment: When/how are you triggering the JavaScript play function? If you trigger it when the page is newly loaded, then I believe this counts as an autoplay.

Comment: It plays when the `audioPlayerData` props change. Example format: `audioPlayerData: {command: 'play', url: 'http://....'}`

Comment: And how does this change get triggered? Is this user actively choosing to change the props by clicking a button or is this something that happens when a page is newly loaded or API data is changing? That kind of thing? iOS will prevent any autoplay that hasn't been actively caused by the user.

Comment: You can find some links of this behaviour online. For example: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=134925 There is even a SO answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179585/playing-audio-on-ipad

Comment: Hmmmm.. the user hits play, which dispatches a Flux action. Maybe that's why. Flux sets a global reactive variable that affects the props passed into `AudioPlayer`. So perhaps iOS sees this as not a user-triggered action? My other test worked perfectly fine, but it wasn't using Flux. It was using state: `<AudioPlayer audioPlayerData={this.state.data} />`

Comment: Hm, yeah there's a chance that might be it. iOS might not be used to React's way of doing things yet, so they haven't taken this into account. If the user is already triggering that play, is it possible to take Flux out of the equation for now?

Comment: BINGO! Flux it was. Wow. Thanks for the back and forth.. sometimes just  talking to another dev is all one needs to zero in on the problem. :) Feel free to edit your answer so people know this was the issue.

Comment: Done :) I'm glad it helped.