# HTML5 audio works on desktop and iphone but not on ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, audio

This is my code. Sound works everywhere except on ipad. Tried out with 2 different devices.

```
var audioplayer = document.createElement('audio');
audioplayer.id = "audioplayer";
var audiosource = document.createElement('source');
audiosource.id = "audiosource";
audiosource.type = "audio/mpeg";
audiosource.src = "";
audioplayer.appendChild(audiosource);
td.appendChild(audioplayer);

var voice_icon = document.createElement('p');
voice_icon.id = "voice_icon_dict";
voice_icon.className = "volumeicon";
voice_icon.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-volume-down'></i>";
td.appendChild(voice_icon);

voice_icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var myRowIndex2 = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    var word = columns[myRowIndex2-1][0];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = '/polly.php';
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function(oEvent){
        var audioblob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
        var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(audioblob);

        //code definitely reaches this part on ipad so that's not an issue
        $('#audiosource').attr('src',objectURL);
        $('#audioplayer').trigger('load');
        $('#audioplayer').trigger('play');
    }
    xhr.send("word="+word);
});
```

As a test, on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio&fbclid=IwAR2Uedd-T8ybhp-TM4z9KyTxTYRKVmejsNrnb-SSmkZm8EoCSqTMRHhQ63E) link the neigh sound plays on ipad so it's not an ipad setting or volume issue.
Any ideas?

Comment: Same question, different title...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179585/playing-audio-on-ipad#8259634
Try that solution.

Comment: @DressyFiddle how is that supposed to be a solution? It's about autoplay, while in my case the user triggers the play. I'm over this